# How to prevent GoogleMap widget from rebuilding when changing its parent?

Tags: flutter

The concept is simple. I created a Scaffold with `bottomNavigationbar` that can replace the `body` of `Scaffold` when tapped. `OrderPage` should contain a `GoogleMap` widget.

```dart
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String routeName = '/home';
  final List<Widget> list = [
    OrderPage(),
    PaymentPage(),
    AccountPage(),
  ];
  @override
  MainScreenState createState() => MainScreenState();
}

class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  int index = 0;
  MainScreenState();
  void navigationHandler(int value) {
    setState(() {
      index = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.airport_shuttle), title: Text("Book")),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.attach_money), title: Text("Payment")),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_box), title: Text("Account")),
          ],
          selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
          currentIndex: index,
          onTap: navigationHandler,
        ),
        body: widget.list[index],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `OrderPage`:

```
class OrderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  OrderPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  OrderPageState createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return OrderPageState();
  }
}

class OrderPageState extends State<OrderPage> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  final LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -2.677433);
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("map sample app"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: _center, zoom: 11.0));,
    );
  }
}
```

The current problem of this implementation is every time i changed tabs and went back to the `OrderPage` , it seems to automatically rebuild, which cost a request.

I tried using PageStorage to save the state of `OrderPage`, but it is still rebuilt.
Any idea or concept or suggestion on preventing OrderPage to rebuild is welcomed.

Comment: You can move it into a stateful widget then save a reference to the widget and pass as child to its parents

Comment: hmm this is interesting, can you explain why we must use stateful widget instead of stateless one?

Comment: Since Stateless widget doesn't keep the state when it is removed from widget tree, it will be rebuilt when you insert it back into widget tree

Comment: actually, moving it into stateful widget didnt work for me, as it somehow also rebuild that widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to prevent the map from reloading by using `IndexedStack` for the body of my `Scaffold`. This way all pages can be stored and will not be rebuilt when i switch tabs.